# Error with DoMatchParen in vim

Tags: vim

When trying to set DoMatchParen I get the following error: E492: Not an editor command: DoMatchParen. I thought that pi_paren is a standard plugin. What could be the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too get that error when I do `:DoMatchParen`, but this is because I switched off this feature in my `.vimrc` with the following line:

```
:let loaded_matchparen = 1
```

Could it be that either your personal `.vimrc` or a system-wide configuration has this option switched off? You may wish to try putting:

```
:let loaded_matchparen = 0
```

in your `.vimrc` file to see whether that allows the feature to load properly. You can find (or create) your `.vimrc` file in the following places:

```
    Recommended place for your personal initializations:
            Unix                $HOME/.vimrc
            OS/2                $HOME/.vimrc or $VIM/.vimrc (or _vimrc)
            MS-DOS and Win32    $HOME/_vimrc or $VIM/_vimrc
            Amiga               s:.vimrc or $VIM/.vimrc
```

(info taken from vim's `:help vimrc` command output).

Comment: If it is switched off, how coud I load this option? in vimrc there is nothing regarding it.

Comment: Thanks Tim for the quick reply, but I stil get that strange error. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that in vimrc I set:
"autocmd FyleType php DoMatchParen"?

Comment: (I'm hoping FyleType is simply a typo for FileType. :-) ) The `:help autocmd` says: "While testing autocommands, you might find the 'verbose' option to be useful: `:set verbose=9` This setting makes Vim echo the autocommands as it executes them." Could this help you work out what's happening?

Comment: it was a typo. My bad :p. Anyway, I can't figure out what is the problem. I just commented out the line with DoMatchParen (as a temporary solution). Thanks for trying to help me Tim!

Comment: You're welcome. :-) If you're happy with your temporary solution, that's great. If you want to investigate it further, posting your whole `.vimrc` somewhere might help, as might telling us what operating system and vim version you're using. But if that's all too much hard work, dont' worry. Good luck!